# how to find some String element getting from excel data in set? .contains method is not working in my case

Tags: java, spring

There is one utility method in my code it gives me Set of roles. I am reading data from excel I wanted to check the received data from excel is present in the set or not? I am using contains method but it gives me wrong result even if the elements is exist in the set.
            I tried contains() method with my code. It contains() method is working with hardcoded values. But it is not working with real data from excel file.

```
    roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    String loggedInRole = UtilityMethods.getLoggedInUserRole();
    rolesUnderLoggedInUser = commonService.getRolesByloggedInUserRole(loggedInRole);
```

System.out.println("testing : "+rolesUnderLoggedInUser.contains(roleName)); // not getting proper result

```
System.out.println("testing : "+rolesUnderLoggedInUser.contains("SCHOOL_ADMIN")); // with hardcoded value it gives me correct result
```

Comment: What's `roleName` and where did you assign its value?

Comment: @LHCHIN  yes it gets assigned from excel data.

Comment: Maybe you can print the `roleName` first before `rolesUnderLoggedInUser.contains(roleName)`.

Comment: @LHCHIN  yes I tried already.  value is getting printed on the console. printed value also matches with the returned Set values.

Comment: Okay! Because I don't know the datatype of `roleName`, maybe you can try this `rolesUnderLoggedInUser.contains(roleName.toString())`.

Comment: @LHCHIN roleName is already String Type.

Comment: @LHCHIN console output with code : 
System.out.println("role name from excel file : "+roleName);
     System.out.println("with data from excel  : "+rolesUnderLoggedInUser.contains(roleName));
     System.out.println("with hardcoded value : "+rolesUnderLoggedInUser.contains("SCHOOl_ADMIN"));

output : role name from excel file : SCHOOL_ADMIN
with data from excel  : false
with hardcoded value : true

Comment: `rolesUnderLoggedInUser.contains("SCHOOl_ADMIN"))` should be `rolesUnderLoggedInUser.contains("SCHOOL_ADMIN"))`? Is it a typo?

Comment: @LHCHIN Thank you so much you made my day it was my mistake I wasted 2 days for it.